# How to add a prefix to a file before upload?

Tags: php, modx, plupload, uploading

CMS (Modx Evolution) that I`m currently using has ability to print some informations into site (like date/username etc.). I want to use those functions to work with plupload.

Is it possible to add a prefix or completely rename file after (or before uploading) to server trough plupload depending on which user is actually logged in?

Example:

- user uploads file test.txt,
- on server it will look username_test.txt

Comment: post your code here. Then only we can give some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$username = 'username';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $username.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload the file first then rename it

```
<?php rename("/tmp/test.txt", "/tmp/".$usernameVar."_test.txt"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have access to the username using `$modx->getLoginUserName()`
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/Evo1/getLoginUserName

Either set the filename in the plupload config (I think using the `file_data_name` config option), or rename it server-side after it's been uploaded.